# How to fetch date to output in a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a `flight` model, which has a `date` field.

I am creating an update form and, so far, it works. But, I also want it to show the already stored values.

I can show every value but the date.

This is my `forms.py`:

```
class UpdateFlight(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateFlight, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].widget = forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'})
        self.fields['flight_id'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})


    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = ('date', 'flight_id', 'company', 'airport')
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='../accounts/login/')
def flight_upd(request, id):
    fs = Flight.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateFlight(request.POST, instance=fs)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('flights')
    else:
        form = UpdateFlight(initial={'date': fs.date, 'flight_id': fs.flight_id, 'company': fs.company, 'airport': fs.airport})
    return render(request, 'backend/flight_update.html', {'form': form, 'fs': fs})
```

And this is my html file:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-first-name">Data</label>
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                                        {{form.date}}
                                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not related to the timepicker you are using? If you try to render it outside that datetimepicker1 `div` does it work?

Comment: @drec4s just tried and yes it does work... i don't know why it doesn't work. On the `create` page the timepicker works fine. But, then again, it doesn't need to fetch data from the database.